# Как найти ошибку в запросе?

Tags: c#, oracle

Есть большой запрос, который не работает. В исключении написано что `{"ORA-00911: неверный символ"}`. Я хочу сконвертировать этот запрос в обычный `pl/sql`-запрос, и в профилировщике посмотреть в чем у меня косяк. Подскажите как сделать

```
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(command, conn))
try
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("DATA",  t[0]));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("KOLZNACH",  t[1]));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("DATAGPS",  t[2]));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("SHIROTA",  t[3]));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("DOLGOTA",  t[4]));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("SKOROST",  t[5]));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("OBOROTIGD1", t[7]));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("RASHODGD1",  t[9]));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("OBOROTIGD2", t[11]));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("RASHODGD2",  t[13]));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("RASHODDG1", t[15]));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("RASHODDG2", t[17]));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("SUDNO", "0"));

    var xz = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (OracleException ex)
{
    var zz = ex.Message;
}
```

Comment: Для Sql server  есть профайлер, который показывает все запросы, выполняемые на сервере. Возможно есть [что то подобное](https://stackoverflow.com/q/148648/312041) для oracle

Comment: @tym32167 а нет такого - сконвертировать мой код в sql запрос?

Comment: это я без понятия

Comment: Есть подозрение, что проблема в языковой локале. У вас тут широта и долгота,а это скорее всего вещественный тип. На одной машине может быть задана точка, как делитель, а на другой запятая. Вы вставляете дробный тип через запятую, а сервер ожидает точку и наоборот.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня подозрение, что проблема языковой локале.

У вас есть широта и долгота, которые я уверен на 99,9% являются вещественными типами.

На одной машине у вас может быть делителем точка, а на сервере запятая => вы отправляете дробное числе с делителем точкой и сервер не понимает, что с этим делать...

Если не в этом проблема, то диагностировать колонку можно методом научного тыка, начав свой запрос с 1 колонкой и постепенно к нему добавляя новые колонки. Когда запрос упадет, то именно в этой колонке и будет проблема. Откроете DataTable и посмотрите, что там не так.